# Center and fill image in container and in proportion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm wanting to get the images to fill the the containing div's as well as centering the images in the div's which in this case is the div's with the class name "SlideImage". I know that they can have this done by turning them into background images but this isn't possible on this project.

I've had a go at doing the javascript myself but occasionally they kick out the images so the right hand side is centered in the div and has seemed to be at random times and on different browsers and devices when it does so.

HTML

```
<div class="imageHolder">
    <div class="first SlideImage">
        <img src="img/img_dummies/coopers_beach_1.jpg" alt="Coopers Beach"/>
    </div>
    <div class="second SlideImage">
        <img src="img/img_dummies/coopers_beach_2.jpg" alt="Coopers Beach"/>
    </div>
    <div class="third SlideImage">
        <img src="img/img_dummies/coopers_beach_3.jpg" alt="Coopers Beach"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.imageHolder{
    float:left;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:764px;
    height:339px;
}
.imageHolder .SlideImage{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
.imageHolder .SlideImage img{
    position:absolute;
}
.imageHolder .first.SlideImage{
    width:381px;
    height:339px;
    margin-right:1px;
}
.imageHolder .second.SlideImage{
    margin-bottom:1px;
}
.imageHolder .second.SlideImage, .imageHolder .third.SlideImage{
    width:382px;
    height:169px;
}
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    $(".SlideImage").each(function () {
        var container = $(this),
            img = $(this).find("img"),
            margin;
        if (img.width() / container.width() < img.height() / container.height()) {
            img.css("width", container.width());
            margin = -(img.height() * img.width() / container.width() - container.height()) / 2;
            img.css("margin-top", margin);
        } else {
            img.css("height", container.height());
            margin = -(img.width() * img.height() / container.height() - container.width()) / 2;
            img.css("margin-left", margin);
        }
    });
});
```

If you need more info, just let me know.
Thanks